# In spark dataframe union what happens to the parent dataframes in memory after the union?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark dataframe union what happens to the parent dataframes in memory after the union and if there is a memory or CPU footprint how do I perform garbage collection?

```
val childDf = parentDf1.union(parentDf2)
```

Does the union cause a cache or persist on the parent dataframes?

Does

```
parentDf1.unpersist(true)
```

have any effect?

Since spark has lazy evaluation it stands to reason that if I never reference parent df's parentDf1 parentDf2 they will not be cached or persisted.

Do the parent dataframes have any other impact on memory or CPU after the union?

Can I make sure that no trace of parentDf1 and parentDf2 lingers after they are used?

Answer (score 1):

Functionally you need do nothing on RDD or parent RDDs, as when they are no longer needed - they will be - as Java Objects - Garbage Collected. There is an object ContextCleaner that is assigned this role within Spark.

If the Spark App terminates or the Action is finished upon which these RDDs were based upon, then ContextCleaner will clean them up or you could use the unpersist operation to do that explicitly, as you allude to. I am not convinced I would bother, as one needs to be careful; I also read a blog on some side effects: https://medium.com/lookout-engineering/apache-spark-pitfalls-rdd-unpersist-568f9350fe1d.

> To quote from elsewhere: An RDD is an object just like any other. If
>   you don't persist/cache it, it will act as any other object under a
>   managed language would and be collected once there are no alive root
>   objects pointing to it.

This means that if you have rdd1 --> rdd2 --> rdd3 via maps, then when the Action that applies to rdd3 is concluded or the Job crashes and cannot recover, that is a signal to the ContextCleaner - whenever it next gets around to it - to garbage collect partitions and RDDs, starting from rdd3 and then working backwards. E.g. rdd2 cannot be evicted if rdd3 has not yet been evicted.

In your case then: the parent dataframes may linger in "cache" even if they were not explicitly cached / persisted, since Spark needs to store the intermediate results as a result of computations etc. for possible recompute via DAG, bla, bla, bla.

And moreover, Spark Context Cleaner monitors cache usage, storage used in data pipelines on each node and drops out old data partitions on a least-recently-used (LRU) basis, regardless of explicit caching or not.

If one would like to manually remove an RDD instead of waiting for it to fall out via ContextCleaner deciding this, one can use the RDD.unpersist() method, but in the correct code location.

Comment: It isn't obvious and the code is notoriously difficult to follow

Comment: But logic should tell you a few things, but as I state I like the question and also wonder about some of the internals.

Comment: Granted spark is a fantastic framework but the documentation on this issue isn't clear and I've learned the hard way never to trust logic nor common sense.

Comment: Well I could see from doc supplied tgat u do not need unpersist.

Comment: it states that in some cases cache or persist happens automatically

Comment: The question asks about any lingering presence of parents. At the very least documentation should state that parents are garbage collected immediately or with such and such policy if they are not used later on in the code due to pre evaluation

Comment: Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion. If you would like to manually remove an RDD instead of waiting for it to fall out of the cache, use the RDD.unpersist() method.

Comment: just to recap your answer is that the parent dataframes may linger in cache even if the weren't explicitly cached or persisted since Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion. If you would like to manually remove an RDD instead of waiting for it to fall out of the cache, use the RDD.unpersist() method. If so please post your version of this and I will endorse

Comment: I will improve the answer later.